# Consuming Medium API - JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a little problem .. I need to get the data from the Medium API and display it in my Digital Portfolio. But I'm having trouble taking this JSON and displaying it in my components. Could you suggest to me how to solve this?

JSON Example:
https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@mikaeriohana

**NOTE:**
My intention is to take the JSON data (title, link and image) and display it in a carousel.

Comment: Hi If this helps you..Pls select it as answer..So that we can close this question..If you have any queries do post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to fetch the data using axios get.

Let me know if this helps!! To begin with.

You can use mediumData array to render the details as desired.

Here is the sandbox link for you to quickly get started..

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-mirzakhani-o62c2?file=/src/App.js:0-635

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [mediumData, setMediumData] = useState([]);
  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@mikaeriohana"
    );
    console.log(res);
    setMediumData(res.data.items);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  console.log(mediumData);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Very well thank you... That was exactly what I was needing. I just can't put the post title for example at <1h>.

Comment: That would be <h1>{item.title}</h1>

Comment: Line 24:12:  'item' is not defined  no-undef

I don't have Items has state (hook). I has "mediumData". I need map()?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-mirzakhani-o62c2?file=/src/App.js:0-635&codemirror=1

Comment: I have made changes to the code for your reference..We need to map over an array to display the result .

Comment: Thank you so much ... That was what I lacked, using the map. Vlw even I'm already satisfied. I'll just see here how I get only the "title" of a post for you.

Comment: Great..I am glad it helped you pls select this as answer..So that we can move on..Also if you have any query pls feel free to post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220522/discussion-between-drigols-and-sgrmhdk).

Answer (score 0):

I've made my own version of [Medium API](https://rapidapi.com/nishujain199719-vgIfuFHZxVZ/api/medium2/), to quickly and efficiently retrieve data from https://medium.com. Using just 3 endpoints, you can get all the articles written by you.

**Base URL:** https://medium2.p.rapidapi.com

**Step-1. GET /user/id_for/{username}**

This endpoint will return your `user_id` (unique hash assigned to every medium user).

Example, my username is `nishu-jain`, so when I'll hit this endpoint, I'll get

```json
{
 "id": "1985b61817c3"
}
```

**Step-2. GET /user/{user_id}/articles**

This will return a list of `article_ids` which we can use to retrieve information related to each article.

```json
{
 "associated_articles": [
    "*hash_id_of_article_1*",
    "*hash_id_of_article_2*",
    "*hash_id_of_article_3*",
    .
    .
    .
]
}
```

**Step-3 GET /article/{article_id}**

This endpoint will return information related to article, such as title, subtitle, claps, voters, tags, topics, author (user_id), published date, etc…

```json
{
  "id": "*article_id*",
  "title": "*article_title*",
  "subtitle": "*article_subtitle*",
  "claps": "*claps_count*",
  "voters": "*voters_count*",
  "published_at": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss",
  "image_url": "https://miro.medium.com/*image_hash*.png"
  .
  .
  .
}
```

---

For testing the APIs: https://rapidapi.com/nishujain199719-vgIfuFHZxVZ/api/medium2/